# Width Specifier for scanf() - Length of characters to consume is not fixed at compilation and only determined at run-time. How to make it variable?

Tags: c++, c, runtime, scanf, format-specifiers

I want to apply the field-width specifier to the scanf()-operation for reading a string due to clearly specify the amount of characters to read/consume and not make the `scanf()`-operation susceptible for causing buffer overflow. As well as the destination argument points to an already matched `char` array, which has exactly the size of elements, the desired value of the field width has to be, + 1 for the `\0`. The size of this `char`array is also determined at run-time before.

The problem now is that the value for the maximum field width can not be fixed; it is determined only at run-time.

How do i achieve, that the maximum field width´s value is able to be determined at run-time?

---

I did a bit of research and found, that there is a question already made here on Stackoverflow, that in its source, adresses the exact same question as i have. [scanf() variable length specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410690/scanf-variable-length-specifier)

BUT unfortunately inside the development of the question as well as inside the answers, the solutions turned out to be only handled with a Preprocessor-directive Macro, which means that the value for the field width is not actually that variable, it is fixed at compilation-time.

---

I have an example for you what i mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int nr_of_elements;

    printf("How many characters your input string has?\n");
    scanf("%d",&nr_of_elements);

    nr_of_elements++;                          //+1 element for the NULL-terminator.

    char array[nr_of_elements];

    printf("Please input your string (without withspace characters): ");
    scanf("%s",array);        // <--- Here i want to use a field width specifier.      

    return 0;
}
```

---

What i would want to do is something like this:

```
scanf("%(nr_of_elements)s");
```

Or if i follow the programming style of the answers in the linked question:

```
scanf("%" "nr_of_elements" "s");
```

---

1. Is there a way to make the maximum field width inside of the `scanf()`-function depended from a by run-time determined or generated value?
2. Is there an alternative to achieve the same?

I use C and C++ and tag the question for both, because i did not wanted to duplicate the same question for each separated. If answers between those alter, please mention which language is at focus.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Yes, i did. I did not found anything to make the maximum field width variable = to make it get influenced by the value of a variable at run-time. Do you have a reference? That would be great.

Comment: apologies - I misread your question.

Comment: `char array[nr_of_elements];` is a VLA and therefore invalid in C++.

Comment: @mch I'm pretty sure this still will compile in GCC, but it is bad coding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` to use it as a format:

Just to comment, I used `unsigned` because I can't imagine a case when you will have a negative length of a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned nr_of_elements;

    printf("How many characters your input string has?\n");
    scanf("%u",&nr_of_elements);

    nr_of_elements++;                          //+1 element for the NULL-terminator.

    char array[nr_of_elements];

    printf("Please input your string (without withspace characters): ");

    char format[15]; //should be enough
    sprintf(format, "%%%us", nr_of_elements - 1);
    scanf(format,array);       

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @רועיאבידן That´s a very tricky way. I didn`t thought about to build the format string external. Thank you very much.